# How can I connect the pressed() signal of 32 buttons to a single function without declaring 32 slots?

Tags: qt

I have a widget and inside it are 32 buttons. I need to connect each button's pressed() signal to a slot in order to call a function who's parameters depend on which button I have pressed.  Right now I did that by adding 32 slots in the form of on_QPushButtonName_pressed()
but thats a lot of slots.  I was wondering if there is another way I could do it that is smaller.  I have done something similar but I was working with custom widgets so I could just create a new signal in the code of my class but I would like to avoid creating a custom widget for just a single button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the QSignalMapper class.  The documentation - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html - has an example pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: creating just one slot, calling `sender()` and switching on the result.

As Rohan mentioned, QSignalMapper is the recommended solution, since sender() is a bit of a hack. Its advantage is that it's easier to use.

Comment: QSignalMapper is built around sender, so if you use it, you can be sure that the Qt developers will take it into account if sender changes behaviour.

Comment: `sender()` is by *far* a better solution. `QSignalMapper` is overcomplex and adds zero functionality for this use case. In a dialog, first thing, `QObject *qo=sender();` followed by `switch(qo)` or `if (qo==my_widget)`